# awk the previous and current line only if equal to string

Tags: linux, awk, csh

I have the following lines in a file

```
shush1 120 60G
albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G
albi 0/20/60
```

I want to get the previous and current line, only if it start with albi.
Means, output should look like:

```
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60
```

I tried the below, but looks I'm missing something:

```
awk '{if($1 ~ "shush*") line0=$0 ; else if($1 ~ "albi*") print $line0,$0}'
```

Comment: What should the output be if back to back lines contain `alibi` or `alibi` is the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do need to test "shush" as in your script, all you were doing wrong is trying to reference an awk variable as `$var` (shell syntax) instead of just `var` (awk, C, etc. syntax):

```
$ awk '{ if ($1 ~ /shush/) line0=$0; else if ($1 ~ /albi/) print line0, $0 }' file
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60
```

You also have undesirable `*`s at the end of your regexps (which I assume you think mean "any other chars" but that's shell globbing syntax, not regexp syntax where `*` means repetitions of the previous character or expression) which I've removed above and were using string `"..."` instead of regexp `/.../` delimiters but neither of those things was causing your script to fail.

You can get the output you show without testing `shush` though with either of these (or various other possibilities) depending on your requirements for the rainy day cases like back to back lines containing `albi`, etc.:

```
$ awk '$1 ~ /albi/{ print line0, $0 } { line0=$0 }' file
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60

$ awk '$1 ~ /albi/{ print line0, $0; line0=""; next } { line0=$0 }' file
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^albi/{print p,$0}{p=$0}' file
```

Output:

```
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60
```

Regarding your sample solution: You seem to be mixing awk and bash. Your sample solution in awk would be:

```
$ awk '{if($1 ~ /^shush/) line0=$0 ; else if($1 ~ /^albi/) print line0,$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 'N; s/\n/ /; /albi/p' file 
shush1 120 60G albi 0/0/60
shush2 120 120G albi 0/20/60
```

Breaking that down:

```
sed -n      # don't print unless told to
N;          # copy line to pattern space - previous line if there is a match
s/\n/ /;    # join the two lines
/albi/p     # print the lines if the second has 'albi'
```